# Changing line style in Dendrogram

Tags: plotting, style

How does one change the line style in `Dendrogram`?  `BaseStyle` changes the style on the points (vertexes) and `AxesStyle` applies only to (optional) axes.  There is no `Style`, `PlotStyle` or `GraphStyle`.

Must one use `DendrogramPlot` (which does admit style changes)?

```
Needs["HierarchicalClustering`"];
DendrogramPlot[{3,4,7,8,9}, PlotStyle->Red]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in the option list (see below) you cannot find what you need, use this simple trick for objects that generate `Graphics`

```
Dendrogram[{3, 4, 7, 8, 9}]/.Line[x_] :> {Red, Thick, Dashed, Line[x]}
```

[image]

In future more options might be made available:

```
Dendrogram // Options // Column

DataDissimilarityMatrix->Automatic
DistanceCombiner->Automatic
AlignmentPoint->Center
AspectRatio->Automatic
Axes->False
AxesLabel->None
AxesOrigin->Automatic
AxesStyle->{}
Background->None
BaselinePosition->Automatic
BaseStyle->{}
ClusterDissimilarityFunction->Single
ColorOutput->Automatic
ContentSelectable->Automatic
CoordinatesToolOptions->Automatic
DistanceFunction->Automatic
Epilog->{}
FeatureExtractor->Automatic
Frame->False
FrameLabel->None
FrameStyle->{}
FrameTicks->Automatic
FrameTicksStyle->{}
GridLines->None
GridLinesStyle->{}
ImageMargins->0.
ImagePadding->All
ImageSize->Automatic
ImageSizeRaw->Automatic
LabelStyle->{}
Method->Automatic
PlotLabel->None
PlotRange->All
PlotRangeClipping->False
PlotRangePadding->Automatic
PlotRegion->Automatic
PreserveImageOptions->Automatic
Prolog->{}
RotateLabel->True
Ticks->Automatic
TicksStyle->{}
DisplayFunction:>$DisplayFunction
FormatType:>TraditionalForm
```

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  I think Wolfram should include a `PlotStyle` option, however...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Feel free to send suggestions via Wolfram support or via Wolfram Community where discussions are monitored internally. See an example [HERE](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1056910)